# MarkerClusterer and geocoder integration

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, marker, markerclusterer

I have some troubles how to display marker clusterer on my Google map. I tried different solutions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15008/integrate-markerclusterer-with-google-map-v3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529244/how-can-i-integrate-makerclusterer-with-current-google-map-v3) but none seem to work.

This is the relevant code and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMarker' of undefined` because there isn't anything in the places[i]:

```
function initialize(item) {
        body = document.getElementById("map");
        body.innerHTML = " ";
        var positionMap = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: positionMap
        });

        var places = [];
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        var address = []
        for (var i = 0; i<item.length; i++) {
          person = item[i];
          country = person.nationality;
          address.push(country);
        };
        // console.log(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var markers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i<address.length; i++) {
          (function (i) {
            geocoder.geocode({"address":address[i]}, function (results, status){
              if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                places[i] = results[0].geometry.location;
                console.log(places[i]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: places[i]});
                markers.push(marker);
                marker.Cluster.addMarker(marker);
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });
          })(i);
        }
      }
```

Here is the address array for example: `["England", "England", "Ireland", "England", "Croatia", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Senegal", "Scotland", "Switzerland", "England", "England", "England", "England", "Wales", "Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Honduras", "Scotland", "Northern Ireland", "England", "England", "England", "Senegal", "Ireland", "England", "Ireland", "Egypt", "Scotland", "Nigeria", "Uruguay", "Cote d'Ivoire"]`

My full js code:

```
var teams = [];

function find_team(team_code) {
  for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    if(teams[i].code === team_code) {
      return teams[i];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

var process_form = function(team_code) {
    // console.log(text);
    var team = find_team(team_code);
    var player_link = team._links.players;
    player = player_link.href;
};

//process player

var process_player = function() {
  // console.log(xhttp2.response)
  var data = JSON.parse(xhttp2.response);
  // console.log(data);
  var item = data.players;
  // console.log(item);
  body = document.getElementById("output");
  body.innerHTML = " ";
  for (var i = 0; i<item.length; i++) {
    person = item[i];
    name = person.name;
    value = person.marketValue;
    country = person.nationality;
    position = person.position;
    processFormPlayer(name);
    processFormPlayer(value);
    processFormPlayer(country);
    processFormPlayer(position);
  };
  initialize(item);
}

var processFormPlayer = function(text) {
  // console.log(text);
  body = document.getElementById("output");
  var add = document.createTextNode(text);
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.appendChild(add);
  body.appendChild(paragraph);
}

//dropdown menu team options
var processXHRResponse = function() {
  // console.log(xhttp.response)
  var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
  // console.log(data);
  teams = data.teams;
  // console.log(teams);
  for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    team = teams[i];
    name = team.name;
    dropdownElement = document.createTextNode(name);
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = team.code;
    option.appendChild(dropdownElement);
    document.getElementById("myteam").appendChild(option);
    // console.log(player);
  };
}

function initialize(item) {
        body = document.getElementById("map");
        body.innerHTML = " ";
        var positionMap = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: positionMap
        });

        var places = [];
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        var address = []
        for (var i = 0; i<item.length; i++) {
          person = item[i];
          country = person.nationality;
          address.push(country);
        };
        // console.log(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var markers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i<address.length; i++) {
          (function (i) {
            geocoder.geocode({"address":address[i]}, function (results, status){
              if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                places[i] = results[0].geometry.location;
                console.log(places[i]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: places[i]});
                markers.push(marker);
                marker.Cluster.addMarker(marker);
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });
          })(i);
        }
      }

var encodeParameters = function(params) {
    var strArray = [];
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var paramString = encodeURIComponent(key) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
            strArray.push(paramString);
        }
    }
    return strArray.join("&");
}

// the parameters for the API request
var parameters = {
    competitions: 426,
}

// auth Token obtainable from http://api.football-data.org/register
var authToken = '2fe40f6ab37b43cca925d6fac9b05a0e';

// do the XHR request
var base_url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/';
var query_url = base_url + encodeParameters(parameters) + "/" + "teams";
// console.log(query_url);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.addEventListener('load', processXHRResponse);
xhttp.open('GET', query_url);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
xhttp.send();

var doSearch = function () {
  var search_term = document.getElementById("myteam").value;
  // console.log(search_term);
  process_form(search_term);
}

var searchPlayer = function() {
  // console.log(player);
  xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.addEventListener('load', process_player);
  xhttp2.open('GET', player);
  // console.log(player);
  xhttp2.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
  xhttp2.send();
}

window.onload = function() {
    // console.log("ready");
    var search_button = document.getElementById("search_button");
    search_button.addEventListener("click", doSearch);
    search_button.addEventListener("click", searchPlayer);
    // search_button.addEventListener("click", initialize);
}
```

html code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Football statistic</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="input">
        <form>
            <select id="myteam">
        <option>Select your team</option>
      </select>
            <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>



    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA2aUuu3eYJxW4yVvCfmwaeM3znq3_SAZk">
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Without further debugging: `marker.Cluster.addMarker(marker);` should probably be `markerCluster.addMarker(marker);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1. You've got:

```
marker.Cluster.addMarker(marker);
```

But it should be:

```
markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
```

Problem 2.  You're trying to create your MarkerClusterer before you've created the variable `markers`, with this line:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Comment: Correct, the error disappeared. But the problem still exist, there aren't any markers on the map, now I get only empty `places`:

`.E
lat
:
()
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
0
name
:
""
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
js?key=AIzaSyA2aUuu3eYJxW4yVvCfmwaeM3znq3_SAZk:42
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[3]
lng
:
()
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
0
name
:
"" `

Comment: What does your `console.log(places[i]);` print?

Comment: it is empty, without any values: `_.E lat: ()lng: ()__proto__: Object`

Comment: You're trying to create your MarkerClusterer before you've created `markers`, with this line: `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);`

Comment: I see. I took `markers` out as they are being passed in with: `markerCluster.addMarker(marker);`. The problem is still there, it seems that the markers are empty: `position
:
_.E
lat
:
()
lng
:
()`

Comment: I made it work but now another problem occurs as not all of my locations are displayed. Is it because of the geocode limit? Can I fix this with a setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

I used [this](http://subhod-learnt.blogspot.si/2014/02/google-map-api-using-markerclusterer.html) example to modify my code and it works:

```
function initialize(item) {
        body = document.getElementById("map");
        body.innerHTML = " ";
        var positionMap = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: positionMap
        });

        var places = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<item.length; i++) {
          person = item[i];
          country = person.nationality;
          places.push(country);
        };
        console.log(places);
        var markers=[];
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        for (var i = 0; i<places.length; i++) {
          geocoder.geocode({"address":places[i]}, function(results, status){
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              position = results [0].geometry.location;
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: position
              });
              markers.push(marker);
              markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
            }
          });

        }
      }
```